# Server.Transfer not working on IIS7

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have a few ASP pages. One of them is using Server.Transfer to load another ASP page. But the page does not get called. If I change it to Response.Redirect, it is working fine. Can anyone help me?
By the way, it is working fine on IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003. It only has problem when I moved to IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008.
Thanks

Comment: Which application pool is the site running under?

Answer (score 2):

transfer can only support within same domain...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code from `Server.Transfer` to `Server.TransferRequest`.

I have found this works for IIS 7 applications running in Integrated Mode.